# .htaccess: Redirect all but few urls to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been recovering from a hack and there are thousands of spammy casino links from my site in the google index.

I want to redirect all urls except my legimitate pages to the homepage.

This is what I have now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dienstverlening|starters|accountancy|administratie|belastingen|salarisadministratie|contact|over-ons|algemene-voorwaarden)
RewriteRule ^ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I have all other urls redirect to homepage in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a target in your rewrite rule. Apache's kind of dumb about parsing so it's going to assume that `[R=301,L]` is where you want to redirect to. Try adding a `/` in that rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dienstverlening|starters|accountancy|administratie|belastingen|salarisadministratie|contact|over-ons|algemene-voorwaarden)
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This catches the spammy links in the google index, but I get an error "this page is not redirecting properly". Do we need to add something else?

Comment: Hi John, is there anything else we can try?

Comment: @Forza you can try including `index.php` as part of that long list of URI's, and perhaps right above that include `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. After adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` the redirect stopped working entirely and I got the casino pages again :(

Comment: Here you can see what I am trying to redirect: https://www.google.nl/search?q=site:dejonghaccountants.nl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=hPcnVviINYu5ygPhobTQBw (all those /21, /bonus1 and /58 urls and /sitemap_2.php, etc)

Comment: It is important that Google knows that these url's no longer exist. This was a hack specifically targeted against Google referrers. I hope the redirect will remove these links from the index eventually. There are just too much to manually remove one by one

Comment: It was not working because of the Falcon cache engine of my Wordfence security plugin... Now that I have disabled the caching the redirect is working properly :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any way to apply this to Blogger?